# URLConnection.setRequestProperty() not working?

Tags: java, http, urlconnection, genius-api

I'm trying to integrate the [Genius API](https://docs.genius.com) into my Java program but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing with making the actual HTTP request.
Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("https://api.genius.com/search?q=juice").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer TOKEN");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

return content.toString();
```

(where TOKEN is my Genius auth token)

but I'm getting an IOException with a 403 forbidden message.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.genius.com/search?q=juice
```

This same request worked when I tried with [Hurl.it](http://hurl.it):
[image]

so I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. When I tried printing out the headers to see if they went through, I got this:

```
System.out.println("auth: " + connection.getHeaderField("Authorization"));
System.out.println("content: " + connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type"));

/** output */
auth: null
content: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I would appreciate any help here - thank you!!

Comment: `getHeaderField()` yields headers of the *response.*

Comment: Gotcha - what would be a good way to ensure the header fields I set went through properly?